# simple birth date form in jsf

Tags: jsf

is there any example of simple form, for input date of birth in jsf..
thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Tomahawk's `<t:inputDate>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_inputDate.html).

Using it is as simple as:

```
<t:inputDate type="date" 
       popupCalendar="false" value="#{yourBean.yourDateValue}" />
```

You should add the [tomahawk jar](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/download.html) file to your classpath in order to use it, and import the tomahawk namespace:

```
xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
```

Comment: can you give me an example for imlement it?

Comment: ought i to add any library for implement it?

Comment: @irwan it is as simple as in the example shown in the link I gave. Yes, you should add the tomahawk jar to your classpath

Comment: where i can get the classpath of tomhawk jar? i try to browse it but i can't find that..

Comment: @irwan - if my answer works for you, come back and mark the answer as accepted (tick below the vote counter)

Comment: I've tried to using tomahawk, but there is error occured. here an error result:        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ExtensionsFilter not correctly configured. Resource mapping missing. Resources cant be delivered. Please see: http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/extensionsFilter.html
        what must i do for resolve it?